# RESTful Web Service - Where and how to return an error with additional metadata?

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

The question says it all. I am dealing with a complex RESTful Web Service and I'd like to return response with more information than just 400-something or 500-something. I need to add a reason why the request failed.

How would you accomplish this with WCF 4.0?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you care about the HTTP status codes? If not you could respond to all of them with a special data contract that indicates your application specific errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach is to return a specific code along with a response body that contains human-readable information describing the error in more detail.

One technique for this in WCF is to throw [this form of WebFaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989075.aspx) which allows you to specify both a response body detail and a status code as constructor parameters.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to try and keep it as simple as possible.  You are not always guaranteed that a client will know what to do with an HTTP error code and so I try and maintain a commitment to always ensuring that my services return a 200.  To make sure that the client can know about bad things that have happened I inject metadata into all of our service responses.  Consider the following structure:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = Constants.DataContractNamespace)]
public class ResponseMetadata : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1, Name = "HasError", IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public bool HasError { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2, Name = "ServiceMessage", IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public string ServiceMessage { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3, Name = "IdentityContext", IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public IdentityContext IdentityContext { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 4, Name = "Environment", IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public string Environment { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 5, Name = "Host", IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public string Host { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 6, Name = "Pulse", IsRequired = true, EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public string Pulse { get; set; }

    public virtual ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData { get; set; }
}
```

All of our service repsonse types contain ResponseMetadata as such:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = Constants.DataContractNamespace)]
public class EchoResponse
{     
    public EchoResponse(ResponseMetadata meta, string echo)
    {
        Metadata = meta;
        EchoText = echo;
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public ResponseMetadata Metadata { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string EchoText { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the service implementation:

```
public EchoResponse GetEcho(string echo)
{
    try
    {
        // Implement your service operation

        var res = string.Empty;
        var response = new EchoResponse(new ResponseMetadata(false, string.Empty, Pulse), res);

        return response;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        var err = StringHelper.FormatException(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex, Pulse, true, ex.Status.ToString());
        Log.Error(err, ex);

        return new EchoResponse(new ResponseMetadata(true, err, Pulse), null);
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
    {
        var err = StringHelper.FormatException(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex, Pulse, true);
        Log.Warn(err);

        return new EchoResponse(new ResponseMetadata(true, err, Pulse), null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var err = StringHelper.FormatException(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex, Pulse, true);
        Log.Error(err, ex);

        return new EchoResponse(new ResponseMetadata(true, err, Pulse), null);
    }
}
```

So as you can see this approach guarantees that any error or exceptioon is caught and handled by setting the HasError flag and stuffing meaningful text into the ServiceMessage.

The IdentityContext structure is used to ensure that my service responses always report back identity information and Pulse is a way to correlate related operations.  I have stripped out the logging code from the example.

We have built hundreds of services with this technique for iPad, iPhone, WebSphere and .NET clients.